# Rails 3 - Thumbs up - Routing problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, vote

Hi
I've got a project where I'm using Thumbs_up, when you enter a single retailer you can either vote it up or down. It works like a charm.

But now I try to add this feature to a index page of all retailers and it starts to give me error when I try to post the action with a form.

This is the error I receive on the "index" page.

```
Started POST "/retailers/lensesonly/vote_down" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-09 13:02:02 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/retailers/lensesonly/vote_down"):
```

And then when I enter the single page of a retailer and votes it up it gives me this.

```
  Started POST "/retailers/lenssavers/vote_down" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-09 13:05:13 +0200
  Processing by RetailersController#vote_down as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asd.../0i5fcCO7+asd=", "commit"=>"", "id"=>"lenssavers"}
```

Why is it like this? What am I doing wrong? The forms look exactly the same when you look at it in a browser (FF-Firebug).

Comment: Can you mash in rake routes and post the results as well as the contents of your config/routes.rb file.

In your example output you are targeting different routes /lensesonly/ and /lenssavers/ it looks as though you don't have lensesonly routing in the same way as lenssavers

Comment: Can you paste fragment of code from you index page where you provide the voting form/button/link?

Comment: <% form_for retailer, :url => vote_down_retailer_path(@retailer), :remote => true do %>
                      <%= submit_tag "", :class => 'disLike' %>
                  <% end %>

Answer (score 1):

The url's you are showing are different:

```
/retailers/lenssavers/vote_down
```

is the working url.
While this one fails:

```
/retailers/lensesonly/vote_down
```

Are you missing a definition in your `routes.rb` for `lensesonly` ?

You can easily check your routes by running `rake routes` on the command-line, in your rails root folder.

Comment: Hi, sorry, lenssavers and lensesonly are two retailers, I should have posted the same retailer on both examples...

This is my rake routes:

   vote_up_retailer POST   /retailers/:id/vote_up(.:format)                 {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"retailers"}
 vote_down_retailer POST   /retailers/:id/vote_down(.:format)               {:action=>"vote_down", :controller=>"retailers"}
          retailers GET    /retailers(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"retailers"}

Comment: Ow ok. sorry, I was thinking it were nested routes. Then could it be that you only allow `js` as format?

Comment: Well, yeah, but when I use the.

                  <% form_for retailer, :url => vote_down_retailer_path(@retailer), :remote => true do %>
                      <%= submit_tag "", :class => 'disLike' %>
                  <% end %>

I declare that it should use js as format?